# Prevent VS Code from folding comments

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments, folding

I searched several hours already, but I couldn't find a way to prevent VS Code from putting the little folding icon in the gutter for my `//` style `comments` in my javascript and typescript files.

How can this be achieved?
(I would like of course to keep the folding feature
and with  `"editor.showFoldingControls": "always"`, `"editor.foldingStrategy": "auto`")

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be, with VSCode 1.70 (July 2022), to set `editor.showFoldingControls: never`, as:

- suggested with [issue 58708](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/58708):

  > `editor.showFoldingControls` only allows for "`always`" and "`mouseover`".
  > It would be nice if we could disable it entirely.
  >
  > The only way to remove the controls (and save space in the editor) is to set `"editor.folding": false`.
  > However, this will also disable the keyboard shortcuts for folding.
  >
  > Preferably, we could disable the UI controls (saving space in the editor by decreasing the gutter width), while still being able to use the keyboard shortcuts.
  >
  > UI controls are not necessary for simple folding (fold imports, fold a method, etc.).
- implemented with [PR 153764](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/153764):

  [image: demo]

This is available today in [VSCode insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

Even though the controls are hidden, the folding feature is still available through keyboard shortcuts.